# Reading data from CSV File and Inserting it into Database

Tags: sql-server, command-line, cmd, bcp, sqlbulkcopy

I have a requirement to read the data from a csv file and populate it into the database. I am using the bcp commandline utility for this purpose. 
My CSV File look like this:

```
First_name,Last_name,EmpID,company,languages
"Jack","Thomas","57616","IBM","C
C++
JAVA
COBOL
PERL
SQL
 "
"Tim","Cook","10001","Apple","Python
C++
Java
XML
 "
```

As you see, the last column(languages) has values each on a new line. The bcp command has been scripted to check for the row delimiter and once it gets the first value from the last column, it terminates
Request you to please suggest how to parse this using bcp?

Comment: `bcp`/`BULK INSERT` doesn't support quoted text; at least not before SQL Server 2019. You'll need to use a different tool, for example SSIS.

Comment: "Import and Export Data" tool will help you. It's intuitive to use.

Comment: What have you tried, where are you stuck? Regard that this site is not a free code/script writing service!

Answer (score 3):

I don't see [much progress](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53774664/how-to-remove-new-lines-from-the-last-column-of-csv) in trying to find a solution/doing research on your own - what is expected in [SO].

Here a possible PowerShell solution importing the csv,
converting the multiline column to a semicolon separated one and exporting as csv.

```
Import-Csv .\old.csv| ForEach-Object {
    $_.Languages=$_.Languages -split "`r?`n" -ne ' ' -join ';'
    $_
} | Export-Csv .\New.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

This will result in all columns double quoted:

```
> Get-Content .\new.csv
"First_name","Last_name","EmpID","company","languages"
"Jack","Thomas","57616","IBM","C;C++;JAVA;COBOL;PERL;SQL"
"Tim","Cook","10001","Apple","Python;C++;Java;XML"
```

Another PowerShell one liner will remedy this:

```
(Get-Content .\new.csv).trim('"') -replace '","',',' | Set-Content .\new.csv
```

---

```
First_name,Last_name,EmpID,company,languages
Jack,Thomas,57616,IBM,C;C++;JAVA;COBOL;PERL;SQL
Tim,Cook,10001,Apple,Python;C++;Java;XML
```

**EDIT: one combined .ps1 file**

```
## Q:\Test\2018\12\14\SO_53777634.ps1

$FileIn = '.\old.csv'
$FileOut= '.\new.csv'

Import-Csv $FileIn | ForEach-Object {
    $_.Languages=$_.Languages -split "`r?`n" -ne ' ' -join ';'
    $_
} | Export-Csv $FileOut -NoTypeInformation

(Get-Content $FileOut).trim('"') -replace '","',',' | Set-Content $FileOut
```

Comment: When I am running the command Import-Csv .\old.csv| ForEach-Object {
    $_.Languages=$_.Languages -split "`r?`n" -ne ' ' -join ';'
    $_
} | Export-Csv .\New.csv -NoTypeInformation, I am getting the error message : At line:1 char:102
+ ... $_.Languages=$_.Languages -split "`r?`n" -ne ' ' -join ';' $_} | Expo ...
+                                                                ~~
Unexpected token '$_' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParentContainsErrorRecordException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken

Comment: What PowerShell version do yoi use? (`$PSVersionTable`) Looks like a copy/paste error, the lines shouldn't count up to char:102. **See edited answer.**

Comment: Im using the PS version 5.1
Name             : ConsoleHost
Version          : 5.1.16299.666
InstanceId       : 448f3d4a-5248-4bb8-bef0-9a70200435ad

Comment: I am running the entire script as a single line, so probably its showing char:102

Comment: Try running the script `.\file.ps1` , however you name it.

Comment: I triggered the script and It worked. However, it did not work for all the rows. Looking into this issue. Still, Tons of Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a SQL solution:  This walks through your import file and parses the data into two tables.  There are two loops.  One loop for the 'master' table and one loop for the 'detail' table.

Setup

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   #tempTable)
  DROP TABLE #tempTable

/*
Create Table emps
(
First_Name Varchar(25),
Last_Name VarChar(25),
EmpID VarChar(10),
Company VarChar(30)
)

Create Table langs
(
EmpID VarChar(10),
Lang VarChar(15)
)
*/

Delete From langs
Delete From emps

CREATE TABLE #tempTable
(
  RowVal VarChar(Max)
)
```

Query

```
BULK INSERT #tempTable
FROM 'c:\Downloads\EmpLangs.txt' 
WITH 
(
    FIRSTROW = 2,
    ROWTERMINATOR = '\n'
)

Declare @RowV VarChar(100)
--Use the following to get the location of each delimiter
Declare @f1q1 Int
Declare @f1q2 Int
Declare @f2q1 Int
Declare @f2q2 Int
Declare @f3q1 Int
Declare @f3q2 Int
Declare @f4q1 Int
Declare @f4q2 Int
Declare @f5q1 Int

Declare @empid VarChar(10)

Declare @vHeader Int = 1  --Is header row?

Declare vCursor CURSOR For Select RowVal  From #tempTable

  Open vCursor;
  Fetch Next From vCursor Into @RowV

  While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  --Walk through rows to parse
  Begin

   If @vHeader = 1
      Begin     
        Set @f1q1 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,1)
        Set @f1q2 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f1q1+1)

        Set @f2q1 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f1q2+1)
        Set @f2q2 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f2q1+1)

        Set @f3q1 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f2q2+1)
        Set @f3q2 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f3q1+1)

        Set @f4q1 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f3q2+1)
        Set @f4q2 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f4q1+1)

        Set @f5q1 = CHARINDEX('"',@RowV,@f4q2+1)

        Insert Into emps Values
        (SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f1q1+1,@f1q2-@f1q1-1),
         SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f2q1+1,@f2q2-@f2q1-1),
         SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f3q1+1,@f3q2-@f3q1-1),
         SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f4q1+1,@f4q2-@f4q1-1) 
        )

        Set @vHeader = 0
        Set @empid = SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f3q1+1,@f3q2-@f3q1-1)
        Insert Into langs Values (@empid,SUBSTRING(@RowV,@f5q1+1,Len(@RowV)- @f5q1 + 1))  -- ADDED to get the trailing language from the header row
      End

     Fetch Next From vCursor Into @RowV
       While @@FETCH_STATUS = 0  And @vHeader = 0 And @RowV <> ' "'
         Begin
            Insert Into langs Values (@empid,@RowV)
            Fetch Next From vCursor Into @RowV
            If @RowV = ' "' 
             Begin
                If @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                  Begin
                     Fetch Next From vCursor Into @RowV
                     Set @vHeader = 1
                  End
             End
         End
  End;

  Close vCursor
  Deallocate vCursor

Select e.*,l.lang From emps e
INNER JOIN
langs l ON e.EmpID = l.EmpID
```

Result

```
First_Name  Last_Name   EmpID   Company Lang
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     C
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     C++
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     JAVA
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     COBOL
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     PERL
Jack        Thomas      57616   IBM     SQL
Tim         Cook        10001   Apple   Python
Tim         Cook        10001   Apple   C++
Tim         Cook        10001   Apple   Java
Tim         Cook        10001   Apple   XML
```